# Path is not a valid virtual path while uploading image to server in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to upload image to the server, but image can be uploaded locally to a project folder with `~/images/profile`, but if I use full path, it does not upload to the server. The code which I am using is given below with a sample url. Please help to solve my problem. I have seen other links of stackoverflow, but they are not working. It gives error message of path is not a valid. Virtual path and the `SaveAs` method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path is not rooted.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, tbl_Image model)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("http://sampleApp.com/images/profile/"), pic);
        file.SaveAs(path);
        db.AddTotbl_Image(new tbl_Image() { imagepath = "http://sampleApp.com/images/profile/" + pic });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View("FileUploaded", db.tbl_Image.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use site name ("http://sampleApp.com") in your code? I think you don't need that on saving.

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, tbl_Image model)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        string fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/profile"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(fullPath);
        db.AddTotbl_Image(new tbl_Image() { imagepath = "http://sampleApp.com/images/profile/" + fileName });
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View("FileUploaded", db.tbl_Image.ToList());
}
```

You also can save **only** `fileName` in db for general goal. Because in future URL can change. (By domain name, SSL etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Server.MapPath should not contain an url. That's for sure.

Also, don't use

```
string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
```

but just

```
string pic = file.FileName;
```

Comment: if i am using string path = "http://sampleApp.com/images/profile/ "+" pic; then also it is not working

Comment: Ok.. Thanks... Seen Your answer

Comment: But how i will be getting the path where to save image, because when i save locally then Server.MapPath(~/images/profile",pic) is working but on the server it is not working, so i gave it full path "http:....."

Comment: The ~ in Server.MapPath is the reference to the current folder in your web application, so it does work on the server. If is doesn't work, can you send us the exact error?

Comment: Any questions or errors left? If not, please mark as answered.

Comment: I have edited my code and i am getting following error when i run the same code on server, The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Login.Models.User', but this 
dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable'[Login.Models.User]'. Please help to solve.

Comment: Your question is getting a moving target. Please edit your question to contain one question and post another question for your second issue.

Comment: And what is the error message? Please start a new question and explain it.

Comment: This is the error message- The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Login.Models.User', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable'[Login.Models.User]'. OK I will edit my question.

Comment: Please start a new question since this is getting off-topic for the original question.